# Pandas get multiple columns by Index

Tags: python, pandas

https://www.shanelynn.ie/select-pandas-dataframe-rows-and-columns-using-iloc-loc-and-ix/

I have a question regarding pandas, I have a `data.frame` where I want to select multiple columns, from Index 18 to 22 and Index 24 to 33. I want all rows.

```
wetterdaten_valid.iloc[18:22, 24:33]
```

I tried something like this too

```
wetterdaten_valid.iloc[:[18:22, 24:33]]
```

Does not work too. Can you guys help me?

Comment: sorry jezrael but this my question refers to selecting columns.

Comment: wetterdaten_valid.iloc[np.c_[17:22, 23:32]]
This does not work